# Change sliding direction for scrollHorz

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-cycle

I am using jquery cycle, the scrollHorz effect. I know that it has a rev option for change the scroll direction. By default it scrolls left for the previous slide and right for the next slide, but I want scrolling right for the previous slide and left for the next slide. Everything works fine except this and I don't find any answer. Everywhere is the rev option only. Any help would be appreciated! Thx

PS: Sorry for my English, I hope my problem is understandably.

So, here is the HTML code:

```
<div id="bup">
    Some text
    <div id="bfullnav">
        <div id="bnavback">&lt;&lt;</div>
        <div id="bnav"></div>
        <div id="bnavfw">&gt;&gt;</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="bdown">
    <div id="btext">
        <div id="t1">Some text</div>
        <div id="t2">Some text</div>
        <div id="t3">Some text</div>
        <div id="t4">Some text</div>
        <div id="t5">Some text</div>
        <div id="t6">Some text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The js:

```
$('#btext').cycle(
{
    fx:'scrollHorz',
    speed: 2000,
    next: '#bnavfw',
    prev: '#bnavback',
    timeout: 0,
    pager: '#bnav',
    rev: true,
});
```

When I click on the #bnavfw or one of the pager with higher value, it scrolls the text to the right and vice versa. But I would like to scroll to the left for the next, and right for the back.

Comment: Please share your code so that it is easy to understand your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Now there's the "rev" option that will do this work for you. Setting it to 1 or true, should do the trick:

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/scrollhv.html